# Did China lose a submarine (possibly a Xia class SSBN) with all hands on board in 1983-1985?

Tags: history, military, china

It's been claimed [a video](https://youtu.be/7Ae71nLrnXc?t=5579) by a US submariner that the Soviet submarine K-10 collided with an unknown submarine in 1983 and this likely was a Chinese one ... because two years later the Chinese press supposedly published an obituary admitting to the loss of the sub, or at least the loss of a crew.

Furthermore, there's [a web page](http://www.military-today.com/navy/xia_class.htm) that claims that in 1985 China lost nothing short of a nuclear-powered ballistic missile submarine (SSBN) of the Xia class.

> It was reported that a second unit was constructed but lost with all hands in an accident in 1985, but Chinese secrecy remains at Cold War levels.

Wikipedia doesn't [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Chinese_submarine_accidents) any Chinese sub accidents until after the year 2000 (and also says that only one Xia was ever built.)

So, is there any other confirmation/evidence that China lost a sub (likely with all hands on board) during 1983-1985?

Comment: [See footnote 13](https://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/pdf/10.1162/0162288041588304)

Comment: @bishop: that says the putative Xia was "lost in a fire before it went to sea", so the one allegedly lost in a collision would have been something else.

Comment: @bishop OTOH it also says "There is more clarity concerning an accident in the 1980s, which killed ten" which seems to be only known incident in the 1980s. That's a bit short of a crew, unless it was a midget sub. And despite the wording, there's no details about the incident in the footnote itself. The source cited therein is a bit hard to find.

Comment: "The source cited therein is a bit hard to find." Hence my comment. It's only a clue. :)